# How to create plotly offline chart from array?

Tags: python, list, pandas, charts, plotly

I have a pandas dataset where Im interested in two columns `regions` and `total_count`.

```
def print_row(regionCount):
    print regionCount['region']
    print regionCount['total_count']
regionCount.apply(print_row, axis = 1)
```

The output looks as following:

```
Fribourg
376
Vallis
608
...
```

In the whole dataset, there are 20 regions with their corresponding total_count. I want the name describing the bar column and the number being the bar's height. How can I build a chart getting these values out of that list called `regionCount`?

In the following code, I would like to substitute the terms: `food`, `service`,`environment` and also the numbers: `3.4`,`4.2`,`4.3` with `regionCount['region'][0...end_of_regionCount]` and `regionCount['total_count'][0...end_of_regionCount]` respectively.

```
plotly.offline.plot({
"data": [
     plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=['food','service','environment'],y=  
[3.4,4.2,4.3])

],

 'layout': {'title': 'distribution', 
       'font': dict(family='Arial', size=16)}},
         auto_open=True, image = 'png', image_filename='plot_image',
         output_type='file', image_width=800, image_height=600, filename='temp-plot.html', validate=False
)
```

Comment: Please, only one question per post.

Comment: Removed. It was more a rhetoric question linked to the first one

Comment: It can be solved using: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926202/read-the-values-from-the-print-statement-array-to-create-a-pie-chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926202/read-the-values-from-the-print-statement-array-to-create-a-pie-chart)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right but you could use `df.region` as the x-values and `df.total_count` as the y-values without any modification.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly

df = pd.DataFrame({'region': ['Fribourg', 'Vallis', 'Geneva'], 
                   'total_count': [376, 608, 555]})

plotly.offline.plot({"data": [plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=df.region,
                              y=df.total_count)]})
```

[image]